# SQL Server remove records if group by returns same record more than 4 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query:

```
Select Store, MAX(Value)
From Table
GROUP BY Store
```

I want to remove all records if the group will result of more than 4 records of same Store name

Comment: You can you use the row_number to filter your records as per the occurences you want https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-row-number-function/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, you are looking for the [`having`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause:

```
SELECT Store, MAX(Value)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Store
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Zohar answer is probably what you want, but taking your question literally, if you wanted to actually remove records belonging to a store group with more than 4 records, you could try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Store, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Store) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 4;
```